# Datediff() function not getting the expected result in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datediff

I am using the following code in my project. I want to find the number of days by given the last date and now.

```
Dim BorrowDate As Date
Dim i As Integer
BorrowDate = Date.Parse(txtBorrowDate.Text)
i = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, BorrowDate, DateTime.Now)
```

for example, when BorrowDate is "01/Jul/2011" then the result is 7 days which it should be 10 to now. Please help

Comment: Are you confident that the date is being parsed correctly? What happens if you set BorrowDate manually by creating a new DateTime object? What have you tried to debug/fix this?

Comment: the BorrowDate is actually retrieved from the database to the textbox not manually entered by the user.

Comment: What are the values of BorrowDate and DateTime.Now when you debug it?

Comment: the value of BorrowDate is 07/01/2011 09:37:18 Morning and the value of i is 10.15:46:15.7608403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using .Net you might try this

```
    Dim BorrowDate As Date = Date.Parse(txtBorrowDate.Text)

    Debug.WriteLine(BorrowDate.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString)

    Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - BorrowDate

    Dim numdays As Integer = CInt(ts.TotalDays)

    Debug.WriteLine(numdays.ToString("n0"))
```

edit: Init the variables and show the dates.

Comment: Good solution; however, it’s bad style to declare variables without initialising them straight away, and there’s no reason not to do this here (except that OP also didn’t do it). This would also shorten the code by half. ;-)

Comment: guy, it still produces the same result

Comment: bechbd asked this already, but what are the actual runtime values of BorrowDate and DateTime.Now?

Comment: the value of BorrowDate is 07/01/2011 09:37:18 Morning and the value of i is 10.15:46:15.7608403

Comment: @tepke  See the edits.  When I run the code with a date of 07/01/2011 the number of days is 11, which is correct because of rounding in the CInt.